# Knock/Cancel out JavaScript operations on an input search for IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have been given the task to get a corporate website working for IE7, it just has to be 'good enough', so I am disabling any of the fancier/non-essential features that are causing problems.

One of those is the search bar that is being used, which search is required, I am guessing somewhere behind the scenes there is some kind of JavaScript used to manipulate the content because when JavaScript is enabled I can not type anything into it in IE7 (Firefox, Chrome, etc works fine), however when I disable JavaScript everything works fine.

The HTML for the search is:

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:">
```

I am wondering if I can add some JavaScript for only IE7 that 'knocks out' any existing Javascript that manipulates this search box? And what would that JavaScript be to knock/cancel out the existing JavaScript running on the search box.

Comment: May be easier to debug and fix JS... But consider simply removing search box and inserting similarly styled one that does not match whatever JS selectors are picking it up...

Comment: Thanks Alexei, that is a really good idea.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if I can add some JavaScript for only IE7 that 'knocks out' any existing Javascript that manipulates this search box?

Of course you can:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><script src="myscriptsforIE7.js"></script><[endif]-->
```

[More on conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX).

If you put the IE7-specific JS up front you can set identical events in place to the ones causing the problems right now, and use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) to stop it from causing further events.

As a sidenote: most IE7 JS incompatibility in my experience comes from reserved words, specifically `class` being reserved. This means that constructing an object as `var a = {class:'banana'};`, while perfectly valid, will cause a scripting error in IE8 and older - they want to see the `class` as a string with apostrophs. You might want to dive into this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe I made it clear - I am aware that I can run JavaScript for a specific web browser, I am wondering what the code would be to cancel out the existing JavaScript that is running.

Comment: Refresh the answer. And thanks for the unexplained downvote whoever did it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Niels, however I am a complete hack when it comes to JavaScript, so I am not sure if I will be able to get anywhere fast with custom JS for it. I'll have a look and see.